# How to select a record by has-many association?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have `User` has_many `Badge`s. When I want to retrieve all users who has gold badge, I just write:

```
User.joins(:badges).where(:id => gold.id)
```

But how to retrieve all users who has gold badge AND silver badge? I tried thi:

```
User.joins(:badges).where(:id => gold.id).where(:id => silver.id)
```

Obviously I got `nil`. What's the right way?

**To clarify**: I want

```
the users who have at least two badges: gold badge and silver badge
```

Or you can say:

```
the intersection of 
  'users who have gold badge' and 'users who have silver badge'
```

not

```
the users who have a badge which is gold and silver
```

Comment: Ok. so which is more efficient? JOIN twice, or INTERSECT?

Answer (score 0):

The or operator is not supported yet in Arel. Maybe you should take a look at the [Arel Readme](https://github.com/nkallen/arel)

If you want to use a scope as I wanted, I ended up to sum up two scopes:

```
where(:name => 'Red Fox') + where(:age > 28)
```

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
User.joins(:badges).where(:id => [gold.id, silver.id])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's gold *or* silver.

Comment: To do an AND, you would do where("id = ? AND id = ?", silver.id, gold.id). However, that is basically the same as what you had before. I think you need to explain your question better, because id cant be two things...

Comment: I want 'the users who have at least two badges: gold badge and silver badge', not 'the users who have a badge which is gold and silver'. Or in SQL terms, I want the intersection of 'users who have gold badge' and 'users who have silver badge'.